# How to check if my query is running in method ExecuteNonQuery()?

Tags: c#, sql, wcf

I want to check if my query in methode ExecuteNonQuery() is running.
here is my code in my WCF Service:

```
 public string Execute(string query){
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnWf"].ConnectionString;
            string hasil = "ERROR";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string cmdStr = String.Format(query);
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //I want to check here..
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery().HasRows) //it doesn't works :(
                {
                    hasil = "SUCCESS \n Row Affected: " + rd.RecordsAffected;

                }
                else
                {
                    hasil = "FAILED \n Row Affected: " + rd.RecordsAffected;
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return "Query: "+query+"\n Status: "+hasil;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an integer which will be the sum of rows affected by your sql statement. i.e. if SSMS returned:

```
(614 row(s) affected)

(123 row(s) affected)
```

`ExecuteNonQuery()` would return 737.

So you could use something like this.

```
try
{
    hasil = string.Format("Success \n Rows Affected: {0}", command.ExecuteNonQuery());
}

catch
{
    hasil = "Failed \n Rows Affected: 0";
}
```

You should also consider a `using` block for your SqlCommand as well as your SqlConnection.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I've one more question about my problem, as you can see at `string cmdStr = String.Format(query);` I want to put the `query` some thing like `SELECT` or `INSERT`, why it can't run that queries and only execute store procedure? thanks again :)

Comment: UPDATE: I'm sorry but when I try to run `select * from my_table` it shows -1 but in my database management it shows `(10 row(s) affected)
` why in my success report didn't show `10`?

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't clear, this only returns rows affected by inserts/deletes/updates, not selects. Why would you use ExecuteNonQuery() for a select statement? If you need to know the number of rows that satisfy a certain condition use `COUNT` and `ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: yes, when I use it for insert, delete, update, it shows the row affected..but it's okay, I just want to check what will happen if i use select :) thank very much

Answer (score 1):

you can test the WCF service locally as well and you can confirm `ExecuteNonQuery()`is working

```
int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

result will the number of rows affected by the ExecutenonQuery()